# How to set custom value to identity column of a table in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, model, column

I have a custom table with identity column **id** and text column **otherColumn** and I'm trying to add a row into the table with my custom value.

```
$model->setOtherColumn($otherColumnValue)->save();
```

Above code works and inserts a row with next occurring value in "id" column.
But when I use below code.

```
$model->setId($customValue)->setOtherColumn($otherColumnValue)->save();
```

Row is not inserted in the table.

How to insert custom value in identity column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you provide primary_key While inserting a row, Magento assumes it as an Update operation and it fails because no such identity exist in Database.

However if you still want to insert a row with specified Primary Key then you can turn off the constraint by adding following line to class of resource model of that respective table.

```
protected $_isPkAutoIncrement = false;
```

For detailed information, you can refer to the solution provided for Magento version 1.x

[Model save using setData and addData not adding to database](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71344/model-save-using-setdata-and-adddata-not-adding-to-database)