# Value not getting inserted into db in EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown extension

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.7

https://github.com/EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown/

Hi, I am using this extension EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown and when I upload the city file and import cities than the values get inserted but the region id column shows blank. The region id values are not getting inserted. Anyone have faced the same issue with this extension?

PS - I am asking this question here because I have seen there are already some questions about this extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok the issue with this extension is that when you put entity_id as blank then magento will insert the values else magento will use update query. Thanks to this answer for explaining this functionality [Model save using setData and addData not adding to database](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71344/model-save-using-setdata-and-adddata-not-adding-to-database)